# Is it possible to have a scroll view that does not cover the entire screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, scrollview

I was wondering if it is possible to create a ScrollView that does not cover the entire iOS screen. I created a kind of visual rendering of what I imagine.

[image: just here !]

Comment: Take the `scrollView` to the exact position where you want it to have and set the height and width accordingly.

Comment: Yes it's possible, just use a UIScrollView. Are you using interface builder to do the layout?

Comment: it is possible. You have to define your scroll position and size, set its constraints and set its contentSize to make it scroll

Comment: Oh thank you guy for your rapidness ! ok it's good news tho ! I think I have forget to sets the content size ! by the way, is that the same answer if I want to build it programmatically (because I tried it like so ahah )

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Use the UIScrollView class for your scrolling content view superview, and lay it out on your view controller's root view either manually or using autolayout. The specifics of either method are described in the docs – lay out your scroll view as you would any other view.

Comment: Thanks ! I can directly add it in the "View" of my main view ?
Like  : self.view.addSubview(myScrollViewl) ?

Comment: Yes that should work completely fine, but if you're doing it in the interface builder then you don't need to do that

Answer (score 0):

Yes . You can do it by adding a separate view to the view controller's root view where you want to put scrollview and set constraints. (top, bottom, leading and trailing) .and add a UIScrollview to that view and Set scroll view constraint (top, bottom, leading and trailing) as (0,0,0,0). After that drag another view from the object library to scroll View. Set view constraint (top, bottom, leading and trailing) as (0,0,0,0).last and most important part is newly added content view must have equal width and equal height with parent view.then select height constraint of content view and set priority with low(250).so i f you want to add a button to the root view you can add it outside of the scrollview's superview .